# How can I set up an IDE for bash scripting for Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, ide

I want to learn bash. Is there any possiblity I can set up a similar IDE (as PowerShell ISE and AutoIt SciTe, with editor and console) for editing and running bash scripts in Windows?

[image: PowerShell ISE]

[image: AutoIt SciTe]

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs support bash language and you can use them. I recommend to you to use visual studio code (VSCode). It has many plugins like Bash Debug and you can use them. You can download it from official site ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/))

Comment: I've read about this, but it does not seem that Visual Studio Code 1.64.2 (latest) supports bash.

https://i.imgur.com/3ZI7Y8F.png

https://i.imgur.com/9pugu8O.png

What am I doing wrong?